# Why is this "iterated compactification" construction on $\Bbb{R}^4$ so different from $S^4$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, spheres

So the standard method of compactifying $\mathbb{R}^4$ is to append a point at infinity and then map $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $S^4$ using stereographic projection with the point at infinity representing the "north-pole" used in the stereographic construction.

The construction motivating this question is as follows:

Start by performing the standard compactification to $S^2$ on the copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ comprising, say, the $xy$-plane. This transforms $\mathbb{R}^4$ so as to be a (trivial) plane bundle over $S^2\backslash \{\infty\}$ with a single point, $\infty$, which does not uphold a plane. Denote this sphere $S_0$ and its point at infinity by $\infty_0$. For each plane attached at some $p \in S_0\backslash\{\infty_0\}$, append a new point at infinity $\infty_p$ and perform the compactification process again. We now have uncountably many spheres $S_p$, one for each $p \in S_0 \backslash\{\infty_0\}$. Now "roll" each $S_p$ along $S_0$ so that in the end $\infty_p$ is identified with $\infty_0$; we can do this because there is a path $\gamma_0$ in $S_0$ from $p$ to $\infty_0$ and another path $\gamma_p$ in $S_p$ from $p$ to $\infty_p$, so "roll" $S_p$ along $S_0$ such that at time $t$ we have $\gamma_0(t)\sim \gamma_p(t)$. This realizes our space as something that seems a lot like an uncountable wedge of spheres.

̶I̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶p̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶a̶c̶t̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶w̶r̶o̶n̶g̶.̶
(This was silly, it is not.)

These constructions can't be homotopic since $\pi_2(S^4)=0$ whereas the uncountable wedge of spheres would need to have uncountable $\pi_2$, but this clearly isn't a regular ol' wedge of spheres (I underestimated how weird the topology would be).

I am wondering if there is some intuition for why this space is so different from $S^4$ when their underlying constructions seem very similar.

Comment: I have a really hard time following your construction. I don't see how it is compact, nor how it contains $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a dense subspace.

Comment: I suppose what's motivating this is I would think we could realize the compactification as first crushing the $xy$-plane and then crushing each of the tangent planes, but it seems like that would lead to this construction unless there's some subtlety I'm missing.

Comment: I follow up till $S^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\sqcup S^2\times\{\infty\}$ and then I don't understand how you intend to topologise this, or quite what you mean when you talk about rolling spheres around.

Comment: Well, there's a path $\gamma_0$ from any point $p$ in $S_0$ to $\infty_0$. Likewise, there's a path $\gamma_p$ from $p\in S_p$ to $\infty_p$. We roll $S_p$ along $S_0$ so that the point at which they are attached at time $t$ yields the identification $\gamma_0(t) \sim \gamma_p(t)$.

Comment: Choose a single point $\ne \infty_p$ in each of your spheres. This forms an infinite set which - if I am right about the topology - has no convergent non-constant sequence. Ergo, the set cannot be compact.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So this would rule out sequential compactness of the space in question, but I don't know this rules out compactness since I'm not sure why it would be a metric space.

Comment: Though the topology is not clear, it is evidently a quotient of a 2nd countable space, and thus must be 2nd countable itself.

Comment: And compact $\implies$ sequentially compact in any Hausdorff space. If the sequence has no limit points, it is closed, and its complement is open. Pick a neighborhood of each point that misses the others and together with the complement, you have an open cover with no finite subcover. Since this is impossible, at least one point has no neighborhood missing all the other points, which means it is a limit point for some of them.

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment because I realized I was making what is likely a silly assumption about what the open sets ought to look like if we're assuming any carry-over of the topology from $\mathbb{R}^4$. I think I see the case for second countability, thank you.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think we might overcomplicate things by looking at uncountably indexed nets. I've written an answer using a countable one and show that it doesn't have an accumulation point. Thank you for your remarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the uncountably infinite wedge of spheres $X$ and let $\Phi: \Bbb{R}^4 \rightarrow X$ be the map realizing the construction in the problem statement.

Per Paul Sinclair's comments, $X$ is second countable. I was not initially convinced of this because it seemed we couldn't have a base yielding a neighborhood $N_p$ of $\infty_p$ satisfying $N_p \cap S_q = \emptyset$ for all $p\neq q$, but such sets don't correspond to any open set in our plane bundle and so cannot be members of the quotient topology. Rather, the open neighborhoods of $\infty_p$ will be uncountable unions of "would-be" open disks on the spheres (i.e. disks that would be open if we thought about equipping each sphere with the standard topology and then looked at the topology of their uncountable wedge), so specifying a neighborhood of any $\infty_p$ is the same as specifying a closed set whose intersection with the affine plane corresponding to $S_p$ is bounded. It is clear that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Let $P_0$ denote the cartesian plane, $\kappa_0: P_0 \rightarrow S_0$ the compactification map. Moreover, given $\kappa_0(x_p,y_p):=p\in S_0$, let $P_{p}$ be the plane attached to $\kappa_0(p)$ and let $\kappa_p : P_p \rightarrow S_p$ be its compactification. To show $X$ is not compact, consider the [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) $(N,\leq_{pre})$ defined by $$N:=\{z_{\alpha}\in S_{p_{\alpha}} \; | \; z_{\alpha} =(\kappa_{p_{\alpha}}\circ \kappa_0)(x_{p_{\alpha}},y_{p_{\alpha}},0,0), p_{\alpha} \in P_0\}$$ and preorder $$z_{\alpha}\leq_{pre} z_{\beta} 
 \Leftrightarrow x_{p_{\alpha}}^2+y_{p_{\alpha}}^2 \leq x_{p_{\beta}}^2+y_{p_{\beta}}^2$$

Such a net cannot accumulate at a point in $Im(\Phi)$ since this would imply there is a $q\in \Bbb{R}^4$ such that eventually (with respect to the preorder $\leq_{pre}$) all $(\kappa_{\alpha}\circ \kappa_0)^{-1}(z_{\alpha})$ are in $B(1,q)$ whereas I can select large enough $x$ and $y$ such that the distance between $(x,y,0,0)$ and $q$ exceeds $\epsilon$.

$N$ also cannot accumulate at the wedge point. Letting $A:=P_0\times [-1,1]^2\subset \Bbb{R}^4$, note that $\overline{\Phi(A)}^c$ is a neighborhood of wedge point and disjoint from $N$.

Hence, the net has no accumulation point and $X$ is not compact.

I am still curious if there is an interesting reason why these spaces end up being so different when the procedures for constructing them seem similar.